# Merge multiple text files and append current file name at the end of each line

Tags: perl, file, merge

let's say I have a folder with a thousand files named File1.csv, File2.csv, ..., File1000.csv and every one contains some lines of semicolon-separated (;) data values.

I need a Perl script to "merge" all the csv files in that folder into one by appending each file one after another and also adding another data column at the end of each line with name of the file being currently processed (without the ending, e.g. ";File2").

Steve

Comment: Seems very straightforward.  What have you tried?

Comment: I'm sorry for apparently asking the obvious, however I am new to PERL programming and thankful to Alan for his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aCSV) can be used to parse CSV. The following script is to be run from within the directory containing the CSV files. It is not recursive (a [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) has been used). If you require it to recursively find files, you can use the [`File::Find`](https://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aFind) Perl module.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new( { 'sep_char' => ';' } );

open my $fho, '>', 'combined.csv' or die "Error opening file: $!";

while ( my $file = <*.csv> ) {
    open my $fhi, '<', $file or die "Error opening file: $!";
    ( my $last_field = $file ) =~ s/\.[^\.]+$//;  # Strip the file extension off

    while ( my $row = $csv->getline($fhi) ) {
        $csv->combine( @$row, $last_field );  # Construct new row by appending the file name without the extension
        print $fho $csv->string, "\n";        # Write the combined string to combined.csv
    }
}
```

Comment: That's brilliant, it worked like a charm! Thank's a lot, Alan. Being new to PERL, you saved me hours of headache from figuring it out on my own. Just for the record, I had to manually install the CSV file for my ActivePerl installation by typing "ppm install Text-CSV" on the command prompt.

Comment: Not sure why it matters that it's a CSV file. Just read it as an ordinary text file and append ";$last_field" to the end of each line. `while ($line = <$fhi>) { chomp $line; $line .= ";$last_field"; print $line, "\n";}`